# Why does $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \neq 1$ if $(a_{n+1})$ is a subsequence of $(a_{n})$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

According to the quotient rule, if $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \lt 1$, then the sequence $(a_n)$ must be monotonically decreasing (definitively) and converge to $0$. If the limit is greater than $1$, then the sequence must be monotonically increasing and diverge.

I can't understand why the limit would ever be different than $1$, since if $a_n$ converges to $l$, then any subsequence of said sequence is also convergent and converges to the same limit $l$. Consequently, both $(a_n)$ and $(a_{n+1})$ converge to the same limit, and here lies the crux of my question: why can  $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \neq 1$ if both sequences converge to the same limit $l$?

Please anyone shed some light on this as I really can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: Both sequences converge to zero.

Comment: Have you looked at any examples?  Try $a_n=\frac 1{n!}$, say.

Comment: I can't see how this would change anything. Isn't the limit of both $l$ anyway?

Comment: $\frac 00$ is not the same as $1$

Comment: @lulu Alright I see what you mean there

Comment: @NTAuthority I would like to advise you to use precise notation when writing mathematics: in this case, please diffentiate between the  **number** $a_n$ and the **sequence** $(a_n)$ $\big($and if you want to be really pedantic the sequence $(a_n)_{n=i}^j$$\big)$.

Comment: @gebruiker Absolutely, thanks for pointing that out. I'll fix that now.

Answer (score 2):

Of course that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \neq 1$ generally will happen.

The point is that $a_{n+1}$ and $a_n$ are both functions of $n$ but different ones and $a_{n+1}$ is "step ahead" of $a_n$ so they will take different values at the same $n$´s.

And, sometimes, this speed of convergence is fast enough to ensure $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \neq 1$.

For example, an example in comments is a nice one, we have $a_n=\frac 1{n!}$, but $a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{(n+1)!}=a_n \cdot \frac {1}{n+1}$.

Sometimes this speed will not be fast enough so we will sometimes have $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = 1$

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is just what I needed.